# Ruby on Rails search & Result on the same page error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here the `show.html` displays a dropdown, which contain Roles.
When we select the role we should able to get permission result in the same page

For that I used partial, but getting error as given in the image,

Without using partial when i tried to display in a separate `display.html.erb` file , I am getting proper result.

but i want to get result in same `show.html.erb` file.

Kindly give my some suggestions to attain the proper results

[image]

## permission_controller

```
def display
  param = params[:role]
  id=param[:id]
  @roles = Role.includes(:permissions).all
  @uniq_controller = Role.joins(:permissions).where('roles.id=?',id).select('permissions.*').group_by { |p| p.description }

  redirect_to permissions_show_path
end

def show
  @permission = Permission.new
end
```

## show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "permissions", :action => "display") do %>
  <%= collection_select(:role, :id, Role.all, :id, :name) %>
  <button type="submit">search</button>
<% end %>

<th width="25px"> <%= "Controller" %></th>
<th width="25px"> <%= "Permissions" %></th>

<% @uniq_controller.each do |permission| %>
  <%= render partial:"display", locals:{permission:permission} %>
<% end %>
```

## _display.html.erb

```
<thead>                      
  <th width="25px"> <%= permission.first.gsub("_"," ") %></th>                         
  <% permission.second.each do |cont| %>                              
    <tr>                           
      <th width="25px"><%= check_box_tag :permission_ids, {multiple: true}, 
 cont.id %><%= cont.name %></th>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `@uniq_controller` in the `show` action which triggered that error. Just define it in the show action

```
def show
  @permission = Permission.new
  @uniq_controller = Role.joins(:permissions).where('roles.id=?',id).select('permissions.*').group_by { |p| p.description }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `@uniq_controller` in the `show` action in `permission_controller` controller which triggers this error.

I'd recommend that you define a method called `uniq_controller` in `permission_controller` as follows:

```
def uniq_controller(id)
  Role.joins(:permissions).where('roles.id=?',id).select('permissions.*').group_by { |p| p.description }
end
```

and then make it available in your view as a helper method by adding this code to your `permission_controller`:

```
 helper_method :uniq_controller
```

So the code in `permission_controller` should be like:

```
helper_method :uniq_controller

def display
  @roles = Role.includes(:permissions).all

  redirect_to permissions_show_path
end

def show
  @permission = Permission.new
end

def uniq_controller(id)
  Role.joins(:permissions).where('roles.id=?',id).select('permissions.*').group_by { |p| p.description }
end
```

Then in your view `show.html.erb` replace:

```
@uniq_controller.each
```

with:

```
uniq_controller(params[:role][:id]).each
```

This should fix the error that you are getting and follows Rails practices, for more details about `helper_method` please refer to:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

One more recommendation is to rename `permission_controller` to `permissions_controller` to follow Rails resources/controller naming convention.

Comment: thanks Tarek N. Elsamni, but to get the value of  uniq_controller i need id of dropdown item ,that I am getting in display

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the fact that you need `param[:id]` in `uniq_controller` :) if it solves your issues mark the answer as accepted otherwise I'm welling to help further as needed.